# Htaccess redirection with directory to querystring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink, directory, query-string

below is my redirect with htaccess when i browse
my example.net/video/1 , then will redirect me to example.net/abc/redirect.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} /picture?$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.net/abc/redirect.php [L,R=301]
```

Erm what if i need something like... when i browse thru this link
`http://example.net/picture/1` 
    or `http://example.net/picture/2`

it will redirect me to a link with query string like

```
http://example.net/abc/redirect.php?picture=1

http://example.net/abc/redirect.php?picture=2
```

Thanks! : )

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^picture/([\d]+) /redirect.php?picture=$1 [L,R=301]
```